# MCEdit: How do I see which chunks are unused so I can delete?

Tags: mcedit

I am currently using MCEdit 1.5.4.1. I want to use it to take my current Minecraft world and delete chunks that haven't been used by players in order to minimize world size, as well as so that when they are recreated they will generate with the latest features (new structures, etc).

I've decided that the best way to do this is to look at the "InhabitedTime" chunk property. However, I can't figure out how to view this data on a per chunk level so that I can determine which chunks can be deleted. Additionally, is there any way to write a simple script to identify all such chunks for me?

Comment: If you delete those chunks, and a user were to stumble across them, wouldn't it just generate the chunk again? Seems like a non-adhesive bandaid on something that isn't really an issue...

Comment: It'll generate them with the latest Minecraft features, which is one of the objectives.

Comment: Did you happen to find an answer in these years? I'm also interested

Comment: @Manchineel No. I don't think I solved the problem in an automatic fashion. I asked my friends who played with me at the time to identify which areas they wanted to be saved (wherever they built stuff). I then used the tool to delete all other regions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. MCEdit seems to be currently dead, or did I miss something?